# How to draw a curve in Cartesian coordinates in a semicircle tube in polar coordinates?

Tags: python, math, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def tube():
    theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi/2, 30)

    x = np.cos(theta)
    y = np.sin(theta)
    z = x*0.8
    w = y*0.8

    plt.plot(z,w)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.axis("equal")
    plt.show()

print plt.figure(1);tube()
```

[image]

```
def euler():
    A, B, a = 40, 10, 2

    t  = 10  # time
    dt = 1e-3 # interval

    nbpt = int(t/dt)

    n = 1
    s = 1. # sign of the derivative, initially chosen
    y = [0]*nbpt # result

    while n < nbpt:
        yp2 = B - A*y[n-1]**a
        if yp2 < 0:
            s = -s
            n -= 1 # recalculating the previous value
        else:
            y[n] = y[n-1] + dt*s*np.sqrt(yp2)
            n += 1

    plt.plot(np.linspace(0,t,nbpt),y)
    plt.show()

print plt.figure(2);euler()
```

[image]

I want to draw the curve made with `euler()` in the tube made with `tube()`. I guess I must go from cartesian coordinates to polar coordinates but is there anyway to make the process easier with Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it since the question does not fully pin down what transformation you are looking for. However, assuming any transformation will do so long as the resultant curve oscillates between the boundary lines of the tube, you could use:

```
def polarmap(x, y):
    # normalize x and y from 0 to 1
    x = (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())
    y = (y-y.min())/(y.max()-y.min())

    # make theta go from 0 to pi/2
    theta = np.pi*x/2

    # make r go from 0.8 to 1.0 (the min and max tube radius)
    r = 0.2*y + 0.8

    # convert polar to cartesian
    x = r*np.cos(theta)
    y = r*np.sin(theta)
    plt.plot(x, y)
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


def tube():
    theta = np.linspace(0, np.pi/2, 30)

    x = np.cos(theta)
    y = np.sin(theta)
    z = x*0.8
    w = y*0.8

    plt.plot(z,w)
    plt.plot(x,y)

def euler():
    A, B, a = 40, 10, 2

    t  = 10  # time
    dt = 1e-3 # interval

    nbpt = int(t/dt)

    n = 1
    s = 1. # sign of the derivative, initially chosen
    y = [0]*nbpt # result

    while n < nbpt:
        yp2 = B - A*y[n-1]**a
        if yp2 < 0:
            s = -s
            n -= 1 # recalculating the previous value
        else:
            y[n] = y[n-1] + dt*s*np.sqrt(yp2)
            n += 1

    x = np.linspace(0,t,nbpt)
    y = np.array(y)
    return x, y

def polarmap(x, y):
    # normalize x and y from 0 to 1
    x = (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())
    y = (y-y.min())/(y.max()-y.min())

    # make theta go from 0 to pi/2
    theta = np.pi*x/2

    # make r go from 0.8 to 1.0 (the min and max tube radius)
    r = 0.2*y + 0.8

    # convert polar to cartesian
    x = r*np.cos(theta)
    y = r*np.sin(theta)
    plt.plot(x, y)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
tube()
x, y = euler()
polarmap(x, y)
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()
```

which yields
[image]

---

Notice that in `polarmap` the first step was to normalize both `x` and `y` so
that they both ranged from 0 to 1. You can think of them as parameters on equal
footing. If you swap the two parameters before passing them to `polarmap`, e.g.:

```
x, y = euler()
x, y = y, x    # swap x and y
polarmap(x, y)
```

then you get

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! What other ways are talking about ?

Comment: The first point returned by `euler()` is `(0,0)`. It isn't clear exactly where this point should map to inside (or on) the tube. Should it go to `(0.9, 0)` as I chose above, or `(1,0)` (possible, with a phase shift in theta), or `(0.8,0)`, or `(0,1)` or `(0,0.8)`, etc. There are an infinite number of possibilities. Add to this nonlinear transformations in `theta` (which could scrunch up or elongate the curve in unusual ways) or `r` and the possibilities are endless.

Comment: Ok I understand. Thank you again :)